# Weak solution to a parabolic equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

I am facing problem to understand the notion of weak solution defined in page 3 of the article attached below: https://math.aalto.fi/~jkkinnun/papers/kuusi.pdf

My first question is:

1) On page 3 can you explain why the equation (2.2) acme?
2) In Lemma 3.1 why the test function $\eta=u^{2(1-p)}\phi$ is admissible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is nothing attached.

Comment: I am very sorry. Please have a look.

Comment: 1. It looks like integration by parts, though if they authors did do this then there is a typo in their application of it.

Comment: OK. But can you explain how the test function in Lemma 3.1 is admissible? Because in the definition the test function should be infinitely diffentiable and have compact support. But the chosen test function have only compact support.